# Removing commits without reverting the changes made

Tags: git, github

Hi guys I'm new to github. I just started working on a private repository with a few friends for a group project. I had to make a bunch of commits to organize code, add folders, move stuff around etc. However, this caused a clutter of commits. I want to combine all of the commits within the brackets in the photo into one commit so it doesn't looked cluttered: [image]

I made a previous thread where I used `git rebase -i  HEAD~20`, and this text file pops up, however when I change everything within the brackets I drew from `pick` to '`squash` I get an error: `error: cannot 'squash' without a previous commit`.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Also this is my first time using github so I don't know much about it. [image]

Comment: Could you show the editor with your changes to "squash"? Like, just before you saved and closed it.

Comment: Here it is: http://imgur.com/a/Ec1hi

Comment: Some of your commit IDs in the rebase don't correspond to what's on Github. Look at "Recommit actor and sw". Also note that the rebase has it immediately preceded by two "Create readme.txt" while Github does not. Looking at commit history linearly loses a lot of information. Could you show a `git log --graph --decorate` so we can see the true order? Better yet, can you link to the Github repo?

Comment: @Schwern it's private but I made it un-private for now: https://github.com/Basit-Sheikh/Diggerman

Comment: @Schwern ok... now I made it worse.... please help, I want to remove everything with a red dot on it from my commit changelog/history: http://imgur.com/a/3oH3G

Comment: I got it, used git reset --hard HEAD~10

git push -f origin master

Comment: As a side note, you'll want to look into [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/) for the larger, binary assets like sounds, images, movies, and databases. That will keep the size of your repository down. [You can use it with the BFG to retroactively convert them to use git-lfs](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/releases/tag/v1.12.5).

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD~10` doesn't do what you want. What you've just done is rolled your project back 10 commits. And you've pushed so it's difficult to recover from. Stop pushing until you know you've got it right.

Comment: I removed all those ones, but before that I downloaded the newest one I wanted. Then I pushed the new one lol.

Comment: In my opinion, "because the're cluttering up the commit page" isn't sufficient reason to rewrite your commit history. There are serious implications of rewriting that you should fully understand before undertaking this kind of activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `git rebase -i HEAD~20` is showing you a false, linear history of your project. Git and Github have a bad habit of doing this and it's the source of much confusion. In reality, Git is a graph (in the computer science sense).

Here is the fake, linear history produced by `git log --decorate --oneline` and unfortunately used by Github.

```
1ff521a (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Revert "Boulder code + minor changes"
85cb9fa Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'
47d93ec Boulder code + minor changes
e6bb627 Recommit actor and sw
c6a48cc Add files via upload
1f005ec Create readme.txt
33f251b Added missing files, reuploading project
0b520fd Boulder code + minor changes
4068bca Recommit actor and sw
9b2aa1c Add files via upload
f7ed4ad Create readme.txt
14a6d35 Add files via upload
244e6d9 Create readme.txt
ce33d87 Add files via upload
86ae9a2 Add files via upload
8bec858 Add files via upload
f001fb0 Create readme.txt
d8dbf27 Create readme.txt
9ef59fc Delete Debug
64bfb3e Create Debug
aab055b Created DiggerMan folder (organization)
deb834b Added Debug Items
f219ae5 Create readme.txt
9da61f0 Added missing files, reuploading project
d6459cb added missing dll files, no other major change
42b500d Merged and organized code from last commit.
0a87678 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'
81f93fb Created new base class for objects that can be picked up
67e6369 HUD now displayed and partially implemented
4da4bff DiggerMan can now dig!
```

Here is the reality from `git log --graph --decorate --oneline`. It shows the true relationship of the commits.

```
* 1ff521a (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Revert "Boulder code + minor changes"
*   85cb9fa Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'
|\  
| * 0b520fd Boulder code + minor changes
| * 4068bca Recommit actor and sw
| * 9b2aa1c Add files via upload
| * f7ed4ad Create readme.txt
| * 14a6d35 Add files via upload
| * 244e6d9 Create readme.txt
| * ce33d87 Add files via upload
| * 86ae9a2 Add files via upload
| * 8bec858 Add files via upload
| * f001fb0 Create readme.txt
| * d8dbf27 Create readme.txt
| * 9ef59fc Delete Debug
| * 64bfb3e Create Debug
| * aab055b Created DiggerMan folder (organization)
| * deb834b Added Debug Items
| * f219ae5 Create readme.txt
| * 9da61f0 Added missing files, reuploading project
* | 47d93ec Boulder code + minor changes
* | e6bb627 Recommit actor and sw
* | c6a48cc Add files via upload
* | 1f005ec Create readme.txt
* | 33f251b Added missing files, reuploading project
|/  
* d6459cb added missing dll files, no other major change
* 42b500d Merged and organized code from last commit.
*   0a87678 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'
|\  
| * 67e6369 HUD now displayed and partially implemented
* | 81f93fb Created new base class for objects that can be picked up
|/  
* 4da4bff DiggerMan can now dig!
```

Those things that look like branches are branches. Git branches are just labels on a commit. When you `git branch -d` you're just deleting the label. ***The actual branches are preserved after a merge***. This is called the "topological order" and it's necessary to understanding what's going on in Git. The topological order is what matters.

`git rebase -i HEAD~20` showed you a false, linear history making it look like you could squash all the commits together. Instead, you'll have to look at the topography and squash each branch separately.

---

If this seems overly complicated, it is. There's a simpler way.

The simplest is this: ***don't worry about having too many commits***. In general, having too many small commits is better than having too few large commits. One of the purposes of version control, in particular commit messages, is to know *why* a change was made. Small commits make it easier to associate a change with the reason. Merging commits together merges all the reasons together. There's a lot of advice out there about squash merges, don't do it.

***The number of commits and their size is not a meaningful measure***. Instead, a good commit makes the code easier to understand and review for the future. For example, a commit that just fixes a typo in the immediately preceding commit is not meaningful, like `Create Debug` followed by `Delete Debug`. Get rid of it using `fixup` or delete both commits entirely, or immediately rewrite the previous commit with `git commit --amend`. Similarly, you have "Create readme.txt" four times which is probably a mistake. OTOH `Created DiggerMan folder (organization)` is probably a meaningful commit, keep it.

Finally, ***clean up your branches before merging them***. This avoids the sort of problem right now. Before merging, `git rebase -i master` would select only the commits in the current branch and there wouldn't be any topological problems. It's also a good habit to get into when you work on a collaborative project and your branches need to be reviewed; you'll want to clean up your branch before submitting it for review.

Comment: Thank you, this was very informative! I'll keep that in mind, especially not worrying about having too many commits.

Answer (score 0):

The first commit you want to squash is `4eb500d`.

Github doesn't show it but the commit message ("Merged and organized...") tells why this commit cannot be squashed: it is a merge commit.

Squashing means the changes introduced by the squashed commit are combined into the parent commit. But a merge commit is not a regular commit; it has two or more parent commits.

It's not clear for `git rebase` into what parent to squash the commit you tell it to squash. Even more, if you squash it into one of its parents you remove the merge operation. And these are probably good reasons for Git to not allow squashing a merge commit.

Use a graphical Git client to see how the commits are related one to another and edit each branch separately. Then you can recreate the merge commits and eventually discard the current commits you don't want to keep.